# Bash - list directory with additional info

Tags: bash

I want to list directories with an additional info, ie LOCKED or FREE status depending on the presence of file named "lock".

Example:
- I have a main directory, named "dir",
- in that directory there are subdirectories "dir1", "dir2", "dir3",
- "dir2" contains file "lock", other dirs do not contain file with such filename,
- I want a resulting list look like:

```
dir1 - FREE
dir2 - LOCKED
dir3 - FREE
```

How to do that with Bash?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Nothing. I'm just not experienced enough with bash, grep, find and so on.

Comment: Umm. I have added an answer. Generally, you should not expect any answer to questions that show zero effort.

Comment: OK. I've meant that I didn't have any (even partial) solution. I've been suggested to use `find` utility and I looked at it, but I haven't figured out how to do the task using it. Learning bash seemed to be too time consuming for a single task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
for i in *  #loop through current directory
do
if [ -d "$i" ] #if you see a directory
then
 cd "$i";  #go in
 echo -n "$i "
 if [ -f "lock" ] #see if the file is there
 then
 echo "Locked"
 else
 echo  "Free" 
 fi
 cd ..
fi
done
```

You have to run this in the parent directory (`dir` in your case I suppose)

Sample run :

```
aman@aman-VPCEB14EN:~/test$ ls -R
.:
dir1  dir2  dir3  dir4  dir5  try.sh

./dir1:

./dir2:
lock

./dir3:

./dir4:

./dir5:
lock
aman@aman-VPCEB14EN:~/test$ ./try.sh 
dir1 Free
dir2 Locked
dir3 Free
dir4 Free
dir5 Locked
```

Comment: FYI, this will break for dir names with spaces. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: I've replaced "for i in `ls`" with "for i in *", and 'cd $i' with 'cd "$i"' and it works with spaces in dir names. Thanks for info.

Comment: Using bash, this could be quicker and simplier `for dir in */.;do s=FREE;[ -e $dir/lock ]&&s=LOCKED;echo ${dir%/*} $s;done`

Answer (score 2):

This script takes in a directory name as argument and prints out the lock status (as per your definition) of the directories one level down:

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while read -r -d '' dirname
do
  [[ -f "$dirname/lock" ]] && STATUS="LOCKED" || STATUS="FREE"
  echo "${dirname#$1} - $STATUS"
done
```

Example usage:

```
[me@home]$ ls -R dir/
dir/:
dir1  dir2  dir3  dir with spaces

dir/dir1:

dir/dir2:
lock

dir/dir3:

dir/dir with spaces:

[me@home]$ ./status_check.sh dir/
dir1 - FREE
dir with spaces - FREE
dir2 - LOCKED
dir3 - FREE
```

P.S. The (seemingly unnecessarily complex) usage of the find-while idiom ensures that the script does not break with filenames that contain spaces. See [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: If you use *globstar* under [tag:bash], you don't have to care about spaces: `for dir in */.` is safe about spaces.

Answer (score 1):

And now a simple one-liner:

```
for DIR in */ ; do echo -n "$DIR - " ; ls "${DIR}lock" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo LOCKED || echo FREE ; done
```

With `*/` you only get directories. `echo -n` omits the trailing newline, so it just prints the directory name. Then you look inside each directory for the file `lock`, and discard the output (both valid and errors) of ls. If the ls was successful, you echo FREE, otherwise you echo LOCKED. Done.

Comment: It will print just the opposite of what OP wanted because of the typo. Very interesting, +1.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I edited the code above to produce the correct output.

Comment: Why use `ls` sucess instead of `test -f` or `[ -e $dir/lock ]`, like in this: `for dir in */.;do s=FREE;[ -e $dir/lock ]&&s=LOCKED;echo ${dir%/*} $s;done`

Comment: @f-hauri Because I can never remember the correct syntax. `ls` is extremely familiar to me and just works.